# Using application's *.resx from a generic DLL

Tags: c#, resources

I'm creating a generic DLL that creates documents from models and can be used either for winForms or for webForms. It's composed of a main class that I instantiate with certain parameters. 
I'd like my DLL to be able to lookup in the resource files without being tied down to 1 technology.

So to say, I know how to access my resource files (`*.resx`) in a WebForm :

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Global", "myLabel")
```

I have a few restrictions :

1. I don't want to transfer the HttpContext to the DLL as it will tie it to the application
2. I don't want to rename the resource files from `*.resx` to `*.resource` because they are used in the application
3. I don't want to pass all the labels over to the DLL because then my models won't be modifiable as I need
4. I'd like to place a marker in my document models that is like this `<%resource(Global,myLabel)%>`

I've been looking at passing the class a resource object using `ResourceManager` but it never gets hold of my `*.resx` files.

Does anyone know how to acheive the final goal? Either passing a resource object to the class either picking up the resource object from inside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do this.
In my DLL, I overloaded the constructor allowing to give it a `ResourceManager`object. So here is what I have :

- For the model file :

  ```
    \paragraph
    [
      Style = "Normal"
    ]
    {
      <%resource(lblMontant)%> : <%montant%>
    }
  ```
- For the DLL using the `ResourceManager` :

  ```
  public Reporter(String inputModel, String outputPdf, Dictionary<String, IParameter> parameters, ResourceManager resman)
  {
      // Assigne parameters to globals
      _sourceFile = inputModel;
      _destinationFile = outputPdf;
      _parameters = parameters;
      _rm = resman;

      Worker();
  }

  private String parseResource(String val)
  {
      MatchCollection _matches = _resourceMatcher.Matches(val);
      foreach (Match _match in _matches)
      {
          String _item = _match.Groups["item"].Value;
          val = val.Replace(_match.Groups[0].Value, String.Format("{0}", _rm.GetObject(_item)));                
      }

      return val;
  }
  ```
- For the caller, we use `Resources.global` that is considered a class :

  ```
  ResourceManager _rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.global));

  Reporter _cl = new Reporter(modelFilePath, outputFilePath, _params, _rm);
  ```

If this is useful to others and some need more details, don't hesitate to ask ;)